# OpenCV cvWriteFrame , cvWriteToAVI

Tags: opencv

The problem is as follows 
I want to read a video file from disk and convert its every frame into grayscale  and write it into new video file 
I am using following code to do so

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( "/root/tree.avi");
if (!capture){
    return -1;
}
...
CvVideoWriter* writer = 
cvCreateVideoWriter("/root/output.avi",CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X'),fps,size);
   ...
  IplImage* gray_frame = cvCreateImage(
    size,
    IPL_DEPTH_8U,
    1
  );

  while( (bgr_frame=cvQueryFrame(capture)) != NULL ) {
    cvShowImage( "Example2_10", bgr_frame );

    cvCvtColor(bgr_frame,gray_frame,CV_RGB2GRAY);

    cvShowImage( "B&W result", gray_frame );
    cvWriteFrame( writer, gray_frame);
    char c = cvWaitKey(10);
    if( c == 27 ) break;
}
...
```

The problem is , program runs fine , but fails to write frames to output.avi and creats only blank output.avi file of just 5.5KB

One more thing is i am unable to write only gra_frame using cvWriteFrame , and if i try to Write bgr_frame , it does write the output.avi file successfully.

Please if anyone knows solution, let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `is_color=0` to the `cvCreateVideoWriter` function if you want to write gray value images. Because of that you are only able to write color images to your output video.

It is the last parameter of the `cvCreateVideoWriter` function which defaults to `1`:

```
CvVideoWriter* cvCreateVideoWriter(const char* filename, int fourcc, double fps, CvSize frame_size, int is_color=1)
```

Comment: Indeed. Note that this functionality may still be missing in Linux. i.e. the video will be in color mode regardless of that parameter. That was a bug I encountered a while ago, not sure if it's fixed by now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I created an a `CvVideoWriter` in a different resolution than the image I wrote to it using `cvWriteFrame`. This worked fine in an earlier version of OpenCV, but failed to write frames in OpenCV 2.4